# What's wrong with my Counting Vowels Application?

Tags: java, char

So I was given this assignment in class to make a counting vowel application. I have no idea what's wrong with my code, but please take a look.

```
    package com.practice;
    import java.util.*;

    public class CountVowels {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter = 0;
    int vowels = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();

    int last = text.length() - 1;

    while (last > 0) {

        char temp = text.charAt(counter);

        if (temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u') {

            vowels++;

        }
        counter++;
        last++;

    }

    System.out.println("The number of vowels are: " + vowels);

}
```

}

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: See, the way this works is that *you* tell us what is wrong. Then you tell us everything you did to debug the problem. Then we tell you what the problem was.

Comment: I think the Program looks like chance to get StringIndexOutofBound Exception is that right? @kevin

Answer (score 2):

Your program have infinity cycle and therefore calls `IndexOfBoundException`. If U want to loop cycle from end U need to decrement your `last` variable. Write `--last;` instead of `last++` and change your cycle condition on `while (last >= 0)`. To loop from start to end of your string change `int last = text.length() - 1;` on `int last = 0;` and your cycle condition on `while (last < text.length())`. You can choose a lot of different ways to solve this problem, but the main thing that you have understood the point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your mistake correct as follows

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vowels = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
    String text = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
    int last = text.length() - 1;
    while (last >= 0) {
        char temp = text.charAt(last);
        if (temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u') {
            vowels++;
        }
        last--; 
        // in your case this one ++ cause StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    }
    System.out.println("The number of vowels are: " + vowels);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


                int vowels = 0;

                System.out.print("Enter text: ");
                String text = input.nextLine();

                int last = text.length() - 1;

                for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
                {
                    char temp = text.charAt(i);

                    if (temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u') {

                        vowels++;

                    }
                }


                System.out.println("The number of vowels are: " + vowels);


            }
```

The Output is:

Enter text: santhosh

The number of vowels are: 2